# MongoDB - startup automatically with right config on different ports

Tags: mongodb, configuration, redhat

I have two mongoDBs running on port 27017 and 27018 and now it happened twice, that someone patched the server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 Maipo ) and the configuration of mongodb has been lost, so I had to fix it manually by
`mongod -port 27017 -config /etc/mongod.conf`
`mongod -port 27018 -config /etc/mongod_second.conf`

Can you tell me who is responsible for that issue, so that this configuration is set automatically?

Do I need to

1. enable the mongod as a service, so it start up with the right configuration after every patch of the server?

   - an `sudo systemctl enable mongod` is not working for me

or

2. tell the admin who is patching the server to run this `mongod -port 27018 - config ...` everytime he is restarting the server

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provides [installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/). Follow them to get the database properly installed. Then edit the configuration file instead of passing arguments when starting `mongod`.